# Ошибка считывания с файла

Tags: java, 3d, java-8, java-stream

Есть метод, который конвертирует **OBJ** файл (3д модель). 
**indices** содержит массив строк информации многоугольника, например `1//3`, после операции `split("/")` **indices** содержит: `{"1","","3"}`

Проблема начинается вот в этой строчке:

```
if (indices.length > 1 && !indices[1].equals("")) {
   index.texIdx = Integer.parseInt(indices[1]);
}
```

`indices[1]` = пустой строке, но компилятор почему- то заходит в условие.

**Вот весь метод:**

```
@Override
    public Geometry load(final Path file) throws IOException {

        final ArrayList<Vector3f> positions = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<Vector2f> texCoords = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<MultiIndex> idx = new ArrayList<>();

        //final ArrayList
        Files.lines(file)
                .forEachOrdered(line -> {
                    final Predicate<String> isVertex = POSITION.asPredicate();
                    final Predicate<String> isTexCoord = TEXCOORD.asPredicate();
                    final Predicate<String> isTriangle = TRIANGLE.asPredicate();
                    if (isVertex.test(line)) {
                        line = line.replaceFirst("^v\\s{1,4}", "");
                        final String[] coords = line.split("\\s");
                        final float x = Float.parseFloat(coords[0]);
                        final float y = Float.parseFloat(coords[1]);
                        final float z = Float.parseFloat(coords[2]);
                        positions.add(new Vector3f(x, y, z));
                    } else if (isTexCoord.test(line)) {
                        line = line.replaceFirst("^v\\s{1,4}", "");
                        final String[] coords = line.split("\\s");
                        final float u = Float.parseFloat(coords[0]);
                        final float v = Float.parseFloat(coords[1]);
                        texCoords.add(new Vector2f(u, v));
                    } else if (isTriangle.test(line)) {
                        line = line.replaceFirst("^f\\s{1,4}", "");
                        final String[] vertexIndices = line.split("\\s");

                        for (String indexString : vertexIndices) {
                            final MultiIndex index = new MultiIndex();

                            final String[] indices = indexString.split("/");
                            index.positionIdx = Integer.parseInt(indices[0]);
                            if (indices.length > 1 && !indices[1].equals("")) {
                                index.texIdx = Integer.parseInt(indices[1]);
                            }


                            idx.add(index);
                        }
                    }
                });

        final List<Integer> indexData = idx.stream()
                .map(multiIndex -> multiIndex.positionIdx)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (!texCoords.isEmpty()) {
            final ArrayList<Vector2f> resolvedTexCoords = new ArrayList<>(positions.size());
            //@TODO not yet ready

            return null;
        } else {
            return new IndexedGeometry(positions, indexData);
        }
    }
```

**Вот стектрейс:**

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at com.tosken.ngin.geometry.loader.ObjLoader.lambda$load$0(ObjLoader.java:63)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileChannelLinesSpliterator.forEachRemaining(FileChannelLinesSpliterator.java:114)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:601)
    at com.tosken.ngin.geometry.loader.ObjLoader.load(ObjLoader.java:36)
    at com.tosken.ngin.geometry.loader.ObjLoaderTest.load(ObjLoaderTest.java:17)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: А может там `null`? Вы дебажили? Там точно пустая строка?

Comment: @LEQADA конечно дебажил, нет там null и никак не может быть после split! Да и ошибка не npe

Comment: `parseInt` и не кидает npe

Comment: Возможно, что там какой-то другой не отображаемый символ. Если вы не уверены в том, что может попасть в массив, то я бы поставил `try/catch` и при исключении писал бы в лог и тихо проходил бы к следующим элементам

Comment: @LEQADA возможно что то в буфере

Comment: @LEQADA скорее всего ошибка связана с многопоточностью

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72999/discussion-between---and-leqada).

Comment: !indices[1].equals("") - это зло. !s1.isEmpty() - попробуйте так

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович получилось, а почему через equals ошибка возникает?